# architecting a modern web application

Tags: html, html5-history

I am re-designing my previous century app (which works very well, mind you), and the chance to start fresh has me investigating several aspects. This question is about architecture that works with both modern HTML5 history capability as well as without it.

Let's say I have the following URI structure bloggish app with embedded gewgaws

```
http://example.com --> alias for /latest
http://example.com/latest --> alias for /Resource2
http://example.com/Resource1
http://example.com/Resource2
http://example.com/Resource2#chart
http://example.com/Resource2#chart?a=life's-answer&b=42
http://example.com/about
```

I want every resource or aspect of it that can be seen on the screen be reachable by a URI. For example, the "about" text is loaded into the base template (imagine `handlebarsjs`) and shown in a little popup when the user clicks on the "about" link. But, if the user should also be able to see the same about text if it is loaded directly in the browser, for example, if `http://example.com/about` was emailed to someone and that person clicked on it.

Same thing with `http://example.com/Resource2#chart?a=life's-answer&b=42` which might show a specific view of a customizable chart embedded in "Resource2" using the values of `a` and `b` in the `query_string`.

This implies that either I should have a mechanism whereby no matter what resource is requested, an empty template is first loaded and then an Ajax call is made to retrieve the requested resource, even its customized state. Then I should use the magic of the history API to change the URIs.

Alternatively, I should have a static, server version of each resource in case it is requested directly. In fact, I should probably have a server version of each resource anyway in case some luddite wants to use the app without JavaScript.

Two questions --

Is there some general suggestions for how to approach the above?
Is there any one (or two) JavaScript MV* frameworks that do the above better than the others?

PS: As much as I love the idea of and what `meterojs` is trying to achieve, I am not ready to hitch my wagon to `nodejs` right now. There is much that I need to do on the server side that is better served with something more traditional, a language that has been around long enough to have a complete ecosystem around it.